# Apple rejected app because UIBackgroundModes audio enabled in Info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, info.plist

However, I need this enabled for my Picture in Picture video on iPad to work. I am guessing that they tested it with iPhone, and because iPhone doesn't have Picture in Picture, they could not play background audio.

Apple Claimed:

"Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but we were unable to play any audible content when the app was running in the background."

Which is true for iPhone, but not True for iPad. I need this key enabled for Picture in Picture to work on iPad.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple always tests your app on both the iPhone and iPad, unless your app is built specifically for only one.

If you can't play background audio on the iPhone, you may:

- Write a message to the app reviewers in resolution center and explain your intention. Explain how the picture-to-picture works, and how it makes no sense to play background audio when there is nothing to play.
- If that doesn't work, consider sending an appeal. It may or may not work. It's not like you don't use the audio, it's just not designed for iPhone.